# Problem with calculation od days from date in DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["02.01.2020"]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"])
```

And list of special dates:

```
special_date = pd.to_datetime(["04.01.2020", "01.01.2020"], dayfirst=True)
```

ANd I need to calculate 2 columns in this DataFrame:

col1 = number of days to the next special date

col2 = number of days from the last special date
\

So I need result like below:

col1 = 2 because next special date from 02.01.2020 will be for 2 days (04.01.2020)

col2 = 1 because last special date from 02.01.2020 was 1 day ago (01.01.2020)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `-` sign operator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["02.01.2020"]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"],dayfirst=True)
special_date = pd.to_datetime(["04.01.2020", "01.01.2020"], dayfirst=True)
df['col1'] = abs(df['data'] - special_date[0])
df['col2'] = df['data'] - special_date[1]
```

This outputs:

```
        data   col1   col2
0 2020-01-02 2 days 1 days
```

If you'd like to have only the number, then you can add `.dt.days` after the calculations `(abs(df['data'] - special_data[0]).dt.days` which outputs:

```
        data  col_1  col_2
0 2020-01-02      2      1
```